# CSS pseudo-elements: using attr to refer to an attribute of another element

Tags: css, pseudo-element, antenna-house

I'd like to use the ::before pseudoelement to insert some text that is found in another area of the HTML file.

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <body notetext="Note">
     ...
    <p class="bodytext">Don't press the red button!</p>
    </body>
```

I can use content:attr to select an attribute of the current element, but is it possible to refer to an attribute of an ancestor element? Like you can in XPath, for example (//body/@notetext)

the non-working CSS I have:

```
p.bodytext::before {
    content:attr(notetext);
}
```

I'm using Antennahouse Formatter, for CSS Paged Media.

Comment: i don't see how this is possible with CSS only, you can't select an element then select another one to get it's attribute value

Comment: are you able to change the HTML

Comment: Css is for styling, use js if you want to do dom manipulation

Comment: I can change the HTML, but was hoping I wouldn't have to.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Antenna House (https://www.antennahouse.com/) Formatter has an `-ah-attr-from()` extension function (https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#attr-from).

The function prototype is as for `attr()` but with the addition of a parameter specifying the ancestor element:

```
-ah-attr-from( <from-name> , <attr-name> <type-or-unit>? [ , <fallback> ]? )
```

Comment: most likely nobody knows what is "AH Formatter" and the link is also dead.. this isn't valid CSS code. This should not be the selected answer

Comment: The question states "I'm using Antennahouse Formatter, for CSS Paged Media.", and the question has the 'antenna-house' tag. The link has been updated.

Answer (score 6):

If you can alter the HTML you may consider the use of CSS variables like this:

```css
p.bodytext::before {
  content: var(--text);
}
```

```html
<body style="--text:'Note '">

  <p class="bodytext">Don't press the red button!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm sure he is trying to bind an attribute of some element, to the content of another, not the styling.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa and that's whay I did using another alternative

Comment: No, i mean like in WPF, bind a control attribute that keep changing to another, maybe display it somewhere.

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately my processor (Antennahouse Formatter, for CSS Paged Media) won't let met use variables.

Comment: CSS variables support was first available in Antenna House Formatter V7.1 from 2021.

Answer (score 1):

With css only it is not possible to refer to another elements content. It is also not possible to refer to a parent element. I would advise you to use javascript and data attributes to solve your problem.

Temani Afif's answer is great an i would recommend it as long as you don't need to support Internet Explorer. Otherwise you would need a css custom properties IE polyfill.